# What does "&" do in LESS CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Trying to figure out what the `&` does in the below code?

```
  .controls-container  {
        .flex-control-nav  {
            li a  {
                &.flex-active  {
                    filter: none;
                    background: @color_links!important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know you can do something like `&:hover`, but not familiar with showing a class right after it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I know you can do something like `&:hover`, but not familiar with showing a class right after it?

It's the [same logic](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules) here: chaining the inner selector to whatever is represented by the outer selector. Pseudo-classes like `:hover` and classes like `.flex-active` behave the same with `&`.

Compiling that to CSS will result in a rule with the selector

```
.controls-container .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active
```

Comment: So I guess the question is, why wouldn't you just do `li a .flex-active`?

Comment: @Jared: It's `li a.flex-active` without the space after `a`. Without the `&` the space will be inserted (which is how nesting works in LESS), resulting in a very different selector.

Comment: @Jared: Unless that was a typo and the space wasn't meant to be there, in which case... that depends on the stylesheet. Maybe there are other styles for `li a` in general, so you have to specify `.flex-active` in its own rule. But if the code is exactly as given in your question with no additional properties, then *all* of that selector nesting is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @BoltClock just wonder what's the difference between with/without the space in-between?? What does it call? thanks

Comment: @Franva - Take the example of [.class1.class2] vs [.class1 .class2] 

The difference would be that if you had no space, you would be selecting all elements with *both* class names within it's class attribute vs. Selecting an element where .class2 was a *descendent* of a .class1 element.

Answer (score 9):

### Compiler will replace "&" with current outer selector

This makes it possible to provide different styles for i.e. `:hover`, `:active`, `:before` etc. or any other case as yours.

In your case the inner-most selector would after compilation look like this in resulting CSS file:

```
.controls-container .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active { ... }
```

Answer (score 9):

The `&` appends the parent nesting structure where ever the `&` may occur. So as others have noted, putting the `&` in your example takes the full nested string of `.controls-container .flex-control-nav li a` and replaces the `&` in your code to (in this case) cause the `.flex-active` class to be ***conjoined*** to the `a` tag...

```
.controls-container .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active
```

...*instead of a **child*** of the `a` tag...

```
.controls-container .flex-control-nav li a .flex-active
```

If you just think of it as a "string replacement" for a selector, it will help you visualize. For instance this (note where I have put the `&`)...

```
.controls-container  {
    .flex-control-nav  {
        li a  {
            .flex-active & {
                filter: none;
                background: @color_links!important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...would produce this selector...

```
.flex-active .controls-container .flex-control-nav li a
```

...as it would append the nested structure *after* the class `.flex-active`.